# SQL query works on phpMyAdmin but not Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql-error-1064, radians

I have this SQL Query :

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(41.832100) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(-87.789597) ) + sin( radians(41.832100) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities_extended HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;
```

when I run it through phpMyAdmin it works. 
However I tried to implement it with codeigniter via the **$this->db->query();** function.

like so :

```
$nearby_cities = $this->db->query("SELECT city,state,zip, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities_extended HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3;");
```

and I get this :

```
Error Number: 1582

Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'radians'

SELECT city,state,zip, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians() ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude) - radians() ) + sin( radians() ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities_extended HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3;
```

it does not make sense that when I run the exact same query on phpmyadmin and throught the comman line on mysql it works , but with php and codeigniter it does not. can any one help ?

*PROBLEM SOLVED*

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities_extended HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
             mysql_real_escape_string('41.832100'),
             mysql_real_escape_string('-87.789597'),
             mysql_real_escape_string('41.832100'),
             mysql_real_escape_string('25'));

            $nearby_cities = $this->db->query($query);
```

NOTE: latitude and longitude are columns in my table not variables. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Why are you doing these calculations on the sql side? You could have them precalculated before the $this->db->query().

Comment: when you put `$query="SELECT city,state,zip, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities_extended HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3;"` and then `var_dump($query);` what do you get?

Comment: Are you sure `$latitude` and `$longitude` have the values you think they have? Double check that.

Comment: @user1183771. FYI.. You don't need to do all that sprintf/mysql_real_escape_string code.. CI has already that built-in.. See Query Binding in the user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: @ben I tried that, but i was getting the same error, idk if its a bug in codeigniter, but by using the mysql_real_escape_string I got the query to work. It was really weird!

Answer (score 2):

When float number within double quotes is substituted to its value, php by default will use comma as decimal separator

```
$float = 1.234;
$string = "SELECT col FROM table WHERE lat > $float"
```

will became

```
echo $string => SELECT col FROM table WHERE lat > 1,234
```

instead of

```
echo $string => SELECT col FROM table WHERE lat > 1.234
```

so MySQL will see it not as float number, but as number 1, and some syntax separator.

One solution is to transform numbers into right strings  before using in query:

```
$float = 1.234;
$float_string = number_format($float, 2, '.', '');
$string = "SELECT col FROM table WHERE lat > $float_string"
```

More details about number_format() are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

it looks as if your `$latitude` and `$longitude` variables are empty

Answer (score 0):

You have calls to [`radians(x)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians) *without* the required parameter value. You must include the degrees parameter.

More clearly, you cannot have

```
radians() // Missing value
```

You must include the degrees argument, such as

```
radians(90) // Converts 90 degrees to radians
```

Additionally, check that your `$longitude` and `$latitude` values are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but the problem seems obvious:

> $nearby_cities = $this->db->query("SELECT city,state,zip, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( **latitude** ) ) * cos( radians( **longitude**) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( **latitude** ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities_extended HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3;");

Three of your parameters to the `radians` function are not escaped with `$`... I suppose this is what @josh is saying, but it wasn't clear (to me) *why* the parameter was missing.